# nest list to dictionary with ordered

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nest list like

```
seq = [ [['a'], ['b', 'c']], ['d'], ['e', 'f']]
```

I want to turn this to a ordered dictionary like

```
seq_order_dict = { '0_0_0': ['a'],
                   '0_0_1': ['b', 'c'],
                   '1_0': ['d'],
                   '2_0': ['e', 'f']}
```

the requirement is that

1. `seq_order_dict['2_0']` will get some information from previous item `seq_order_dict['1_0']` to do some thing.
2. if `seq_order_dict['1_0']` previous item `seq_order_dict['0_0']` is not exist, `seq_order_dict['1_0']` will get `seq_order_dict['0_0_x']` to do some thing. (x = 0, 1, 2, ...)

I'm at my wits' end......

Comment: Python dictionaries are [unordered by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). If you need an ordered sequence, you may want to use a different data structure.

Comment: @ErickShepherd: Well, that's why `collections.OrderedDict` exists. That said, as of CPython 3.6, `dict`s are ordered as an implementation detail, which is likely (but not guaranteed) to become contractual in 3.7.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I knew about `collections.OrderedDict` but hadn't yet heard of `dict`s being ordered in CPython 3.6. Evidently I've got some more documentation to read through. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Actually, the ordered dictionary is not very necessary. But it might easy to meet the requirement?

Comment: { '0_0': ['a'], '0_1': ['b', 'c'],  '1': ['d'], '2': ['e', 'f'], } should be the output right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will be accepted even if it does not fit all requirements:

```
import collections


seq = [[['a'], ['b', 'c']], ['d'], ['e', 'f']]


def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    flatten_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = str(parent_key) + str(sep) + str(k) if parent_key else str(k)
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            flatten_dict.update(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep))
        else:
            flatten_dict[new_key] = v

    return flatten_dict

def list_to_dict(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, list) and all(isinstance(x, list) for x in seq):
        nested_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
        for i, item in enumerate(seq):
            nested_dict[i] = list_to_dict(item)
        return flatten(nested_dict)
    return seq


print(list_to_dict(seq))
```

Instead of `{ '0_0_0': ['a'], '0_0_1': ['b', 'c'], ... }` if will produce following:

```
OrderedDict([('0_0', ['a']), ('0_1', ['b', 'c']), ('1', ['d']), ('2', ['e', 'f'])])
```